# How to update hashmap field by dynamic key using Object.assign and avoid mutations?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

How do i define `updater` to get true in `newState.c.x === 8` and avoid any mutation in `state`?

```
var state = {
    a: {x: 1, y: 1},
    b: {x: 2, y: 2},
    c: {x: 3, y: 3},
    d: {x: 4, y: 4},
};

var key = 'c';
var x = 8;

var updater = {
    //Having state, key and x here....

}

var newState = Object.assign({}, state, updater);
if(newState.c.x === 8) {
  wooHoo();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some ES6 destructuring and `Object.assign()`.

```js
var state = {
    a: {x: 1, y: 1},
    b: {x: 2, y: 2},
    c: {x: 3, y: 3},
    d: {x: 4, y: 4},
};

var key = 'c';
var x = 8;

var updater = {
  [key]: Object.assign({}, state[key], {x})
}

var newState = Object.assign({}, state, updater);
if(newState.c.x === 8) {
  alert('True')
}
```